# Fill NaNs in one column with respect to other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a  DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'loading_point': ["Y","U1","U1",np.nan,"U1"], 'product': "FB VV FB VV VV".split(" ")})

    loading_point   product
0   Y               FB
1   U1              VV
2   U1              FB
3   NaN             VV
4   U1              VV
5   Y               FB
```

I want to fill the NaN in column loading_point. As i expect that the Loading Point is dependent to the product type i want to fill the missing Loading Points with respect to the other column.
To check this asumption:

```
df.groupby(["product", "loading_point"]).agg(count_col=pd.NamedAgg(column="loading_point", aggfunc="count"))
```

Gives:

```
                      count_col
product loading_point   
FB  
        U1            1
        Y             2
VV  
        U1            2
```

1. How can i fill the Nas that the value is the loading point with the Max count for the product ?

For this example it should be:

```
    loading_point  product
..  ..             ..
3   U1             VV
..  ..             ..
```

2. Is it possible to fill the NaNs that i will keep the same distribution of loading points for the product ? It would be interesting when there are more different products for one loading point and no product dominates clearly in counts.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] showing a sample input + desired output, as well as your attempt to solve your own problem.

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for this comment. Now better? Still have issues in presenting the a DataFrame in readable form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill max appearance within each group, try this:

```
df['loading_point_fill'] = df.groupby('product')['loading_point'] \
        .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().idxmax()))
```

To fill with a distribution, it is more complicated. I assume you need to sample from the group and then assign value.